# Not able to commit my changes via TortoiseSVN

Tags: asp.net, version-control, tortoisesvn, commit

When I try to commit my changes with TortoiseSVN I am getting the following error message:

> Commit failed (details follow): ---> access to '/svn/RotRally/!svn/act/f8098188-5f84-9c47-9c47-90c8-a09f7e6977ad' Forbidden

[image]

Please can any one tell me what this error means and how I can commit my changes.

Comment: Nope, that's not possible: TortoiseSVN does not use SharpSvn. Never has, never will. So either your error message is from a commit with AnkhSvn or another .NET svn client, or that's not the error message you get from TortoiseSVN.

Comment: no, I Installed TortoiseSVN "TortoiseSVN-1.6.16.21511-win32-svn-1.6.17", but when I am trying to commit my chages from Project(open project Tree), it shows AnkhSvn Exception, even there is no Ankh SVN installed in my system.

Comment: open your eyes: the text you posted and the screenshot of TSVN show a completely different error. TSVN can not show an AnkhSvn exception.

Comment: @Stefan: Sorry, In My System Ankh SVN/TSVN both was Installed,I have uninstalled the Ankh SVN, then I am getting the Attached Screen Shot Error, Now I have Updated my Question,please tell me why this error comes?
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you double checked that you checked out the right name for the repository. SVN IS case sensitive. It's really annoying because when connecting to a windows SVN server, you'll be able to checkout and update just fine, but it'll throw forbidden errors when trying to commit

Comment: @Earls: Thanks A Lot to give me the very important information about SVN "SVN IS case sensitive. It's really annoying because when connecting to a windows SVN server, you'll be able to checkout and update just fine, but it'll throw forbidden errors when trying to commit". Thanks a Lot one again.

Comment: You're welcome. I've ran into this problem many times myself so I feel your pain lol

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me yesterday.
My problem is related to googlecode subversion platform. When I downloaded the project, I put the url with `http://` in read-only mode (`svn checkout http://xxxxx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ xxxx-read-only`) but googlecode needs https protocol so that users do commits (`https://xxxxx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ xxxx --username yyyy`)

I solved the problem in two steps (in eclipse platform not in tortoiseSVN, but I think it is very similar):

- Disconnect the project from the old URL with http
- Reconnect the project to the new svn URL with https

I google disconnect and reconnect in tortoiseSVN and these operation can be done with an only one tortoiseSVM command: relocate -> http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html

Comment: but one of my computer I am able to commit the changes, but not able to commit on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows authentication, make sure that the user receiving the error doesn't belong to two different groups that have differing permissions on that repository.

We had this error occurring for two users and ended up that they were in both `SVN Admins` and `SVN Users` Windows groups.  `SVN Admins` had `Read / Write` permissions and `SVN Users` had `Read Only` permissions to this particular repository, so it was using the lesser of the two permissions.